# Python Elasticseach indexing error

Tags: python, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

Elasticsearch was working well and fine before today.

#### Issue:

Some documents which are failing to index with error:

```
u'Limit of total fields [1000] in index [mintegral_incent] has been exceeded'
```

#### Error:

```
"BulkIndexError: (u'14 document(s) failed to index.', [{u'index': {u'status': 400, u'_type': u'mintegral_incent', u'_id': u'168108082', u'error': {u'reason': u'Limit of total fields [1000] in index [mintegral_incent] has been exceeded', u'type': u'illegal_argument_exception'}
```

Using Amazon Elastic service

Elasticsearch Version 5.1

#### ES setup:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
es_repo = Elasticsearch(hosts=[settings.ES_INDEX_URL],
                        verify_certs=True)
```

#### Code giving issue:

```
def bulk_index_offers(index_name, id_field, docs):
    actions = []
    for doc in docs:
        action = {
            "_index": index_name,
            "_type": index_name,
            "_id": doc.get(id_field),
            "_source": doc
        }
        actions.append(action)
    # Error at this following line.
    resp = helpers.bulk(es_repo, actions)
    return resp
```

#### What I have tried:

I have tried setting chunks to smaller and increased read_timeout to 30 from default 10
like this : `resp = helpers.bulk(es_repo, actions, chunks=500, read_timeout=30)`

But still facing same issue.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a mapping type is only allowed to [contain up to 1000 fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_field_mapping_limits) and it seems you are exceeding that limit. In order to increase that threashold you can run this command:

```
PUT mintegral_incent/_settings
{ 
  "index": {
    "mapping": {
      "total_fields": {
        "limit": "2000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using curl, it'd look like this:

```
curl -XPUT http://<your.amazon.host>/mintegral_incent/_settings -d '{ 
  "index": {
    "mapping": {
      "total_fields": {
        "limit": "2000"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you can run your bulk script again and it should work.

Comment: Sorry where to put this settings ?

Comment: You can run this command on your live ES cluster, no need to change the configuration and restart it.

Comment: Ok we are using amazon and we have endpoint but not sure how to go command line on that

Comment: Still getting same error. even though limit is 2000 now it shows 1000 in logs. :(

Comment: Then the limit was not increased. What was the output of the command when you ran it?

Comment: It gave {"acknowledged":true}

Comment: Then we're talking about another index. Can you show the new error you get in the ES logs?

Comment: Actually it is same as before.

Comment: For the exact same index `mintegral_incent` ?

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to work from Python, try:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

resp = requests.put('http://localhost:9200/your_index/_settings',
                    headers=headers,
                    data='{"index": {"mapping": {"total_fields": {"limit": "2000"}}}}')

print(f'\nHTTP code: {resp.status_code} -- response: {resp}\n')
print(f'Response text\n{resp.text}')
```

You may also use a terminal like indicated above, although I had to add a header, `-H'Content-Type: application/json'`

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/your_index/_settings -d '{"index": {"mapping": {"total_fields": {"limit": "2000"}}}}' -H'Content-Type: application/json'
```

If you need to use curl requests (get, put, post) from Python, [this guide](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/make-curl-requests-to-elasticsearch-using-python-272) is very helpful (it is the source for my answer), and even provides code for a nice method to handle this.